# How to add NG-class with condition and an object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make this code work. I want the result to be class="project project.select"

```
ng-class="{'project': $state.current.name == 'project.select', $state.current.name}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is:

```
<elem ng-class="{'project': $state.current.name == 'project.select'}"
      class="{{$state.current.name}}"></elem>
```

Comment: this would work but controller should have `$scope.$state=$state` sentence

Comment: What do you mean by that?